# site_url() with HTTPS prefix

Tags: codeigniter

***UPDATE**

When I use `site_url()` it returns **http://mysite.com**

Is there a function or an option to get this to return the site URL with HTTPS ?

**Example**

So `site_url( array('use_https' => 'on') )` to get **https:mysite.com**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not specifically. But you could write your own function or just use:

```
https://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>
```

or

```
function url_https($base_url)
{
    return str_replace('http://', 'https://', $base_url);
}
```

Comment: looks like this function/option should be built in to codeignighter. Oh well I think I will have to add it to my helper file :/

Answer (score 2):

**2022 Answer**

This question is old but still ranks high in the Google results.

This function accepts parameters:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/site_url/

The second parameter sets the scheme. So you can use it as following:

```
site_url('/', 'https');
```

Answer (score 0):

1 Hack is to change the codeignite definition of the base url to just // ... // will use what ever protocol is in use right now.

if you use https://example.com your links will use https if you use http://example.com your links will use http

```
/* Location: ./system/core/Config.php */
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) && preg_match('/^((\[[0-9a-f:]+\])|(\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3})|[a-z0-9\-\.]+)(:\d+)?$/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))
{
    $base_url = /*(is_https() ? 'https' : 'http').'://'.*/"//".
                $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 0, strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])));
}
else
{
    $base_url = 'http://localhost/';
}
```