# Can not get css and js files in the server that use SSL

Tags: javascript, php, css, codeigniter, ssl

I have implemented a website in codeigniter , recently I upload it to the production server that has SSL on it.

The problem is , if I enter using "http", everything works fine. If I enter using "https" , then all css and js is not found. And the error is :

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.xxxx.com/' was loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form which targets an insecure endpoint 'http://www.xxxx.com/secure/validate_credentials'. This endpoint should be made available over a secure connection.

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.xxxx.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.xxxx.com/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I have already edit the config.php in codeigniter

e.g. $config['base_url'] = "https://www.xxxx.com/"

but still happen, how to debug and fix it? Thanks for helping

Comment: have you tried something like this `$config['base_url'] = "//www.xxxx.com/"`

Comment: thanks I am going to try it

Comment: it can get js/css , but when I go every page it redirect to https://www.xxxx.com/www.xxxx.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have everything in you error message:

```
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

It looks like you have static link in your html to 'http'. So instead of using protocol directly in your html like that:

```
http://www.xxxx.com/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css
```

Change it to something like this:

```
assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css
```

Also remember that if you are trying to use JS or CSS from other domains that are not configured to serve content with https you will encounter this issue.

Comment: thanks for answering , but in my html I include the css / js like this, site_url("assets/js/jquery.min.js"); then how to fix it?

Comment: there is answer to similar question already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19062775/site-url-with-https-prefix

Comment: that means can not modify site_url to return https ?, as I have use it in many files, it would be nice if I can override that function, thanks

Comment: have you tried to set you base url to empty (if you can): $config['base_url'] = '' ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792268/how-to-set-proper-codeigniter-base-url

Answer (score 1):

Like [maque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3338112/maque) said You have everything in you error message

But it is recommended to use `base_url()` instead of `site_url` for resources and like css, js and images.

you may upgrade to Codeigniter 3.0 `it is still in develop in the time of writing this answer` but it is very solid at this stage and it has better version of `base_url()` and `site_url()` as you can now add the protocol in the argument like that

```
site_url("assets/js/jquery.min.js", "https")
```